# JQuery add class after another one was added and is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button. I want to add to this button class: `space` and after this class was added and is visible in browser I want to add another class: `spinner`

I have tried with:

```
$("button").on("click", function(){

    $(this).addClass("space");
    $(this).addClass("spinner");
}
```

CSS:

```
.spacer{
    transition: .3s !important;
    padding-right: 3.1rem !important;
}

.spinner{
    border: 5px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 5px solid #3498db;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
```

But it, obviously, doesn't work. Why?

Can a class be added to an element only after a class was added and has made its effect?

Comment: `But it, obviously, not work how I want.` Why? It should. Can you edit the question to include the full code which shows the problem.

Comment: post the full code

Comment: just to get rid of the obvious are you relying on the css presentation to see if the class has been added? in other word have you checked in the html in the browser that the class isn't there ?

Comment: I added css in question

Comment: Maybe, because you done have class space but spacer
Also small tip, you can chain jquery methods `button.addClass('A').addClass('B')`

Comment: You have spacer class in css file and you just try to add space class via JQuery. Are you sure if this is not just a typo issue?

Comment: @ArdahanKisbet no, because it works. Both classes are added, but at the same time.

Comment: @KunLun Could you just try to correct your first class addition as addClass(“spacer”);

Comment: To clarify the issue: class A is added, css for class A has 0.3s transition.  Add class B only when that *transition* has completed.

Comment: "only after a class was added and made his effect". You want to add spinner class after the transition in spacer has completed?

Comment: @ArslanIqbal yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could add the second class with a short timeout.this gives you also the possibility to add some animations if needed.

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
  button.addClass("spinner");
},500);
```

promises will work to

Comment: This is, without doubt, your cleanest/easiest solution.  But will, of course, rely on synchronising the css transition with your timeout.

Comment: It works. But, I don't know why I think this is not the best way.

Answer (score 1):

You can add event listener to check if the transition is completed.
Consider the code below:

```js
var el = document.getElementById('someelement');
debugger;
function transitionCallback(){
    var t;
    var transitions = {
      'transition':'transitionend',
      'OTransition':'oTransitionEnd',
      'MozTransition':'transitionend',
      'WebkitTransition':'webkitTransitionEnd'
    }
    for(t in transitions){
        if( el.style[t] !== undefined ){
            return transitions[t];
        }
    }
}

/* Listen for transition */
var transitionEvent = transitionCallback();
transitionEvent && el.addEventListener(transitionEvent, function() {
    console.log('Transition complete.');
});
```

```css
/*transition example is from w3schools*/
#someelement {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  transition: width 2s;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
}

#someelement:hover {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="someelement"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `animation-delay` to set a delay before it starts to run. I set it to a big number just so you can see the delay.

```js
document.querySelector('button')
  .addEventListener('click', event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const classList = event.target.classList
    classList.toggle('spacer')
    classList.toggle('spinner')
  })
```

```css
.spacer{
    transition: .3s !important;
    padding-right: 3.1rem !important;
}

.spinner{
    border: 5px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 5px solid #3498db;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<button></button>
```